# Why must a UNIX user have a password?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, public-key-encryption, openssh

I am configuring the ssh server on my raspberry pi so that it only supports key-based authentication.

I have created a user on the server and set up the ~/.ssh directory with my public key and correct permissions.

The user is currently marked as 'locked' because it does not have a password. This causes openssh to refuse the connection.

```
# /var/log/auth.log

Aug  9 09:05:26 raspberrypi sshd[6875]: User foo not allowed because account is locked
Aug  9 09:05:26 raspberrypi sshd[6875]: input_userauth_request: invalid user foo [preauth]
Aug  9 09:05:26 raspberrypi sshd[6875]: Connection closed by 192.168.0.4 [preauth]
```

Ideally, I don't want a password. I have already authenticated via PKI.

Perhaps I could set the password to 'password', or a random string - but that seems messy.

Any recommendations?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, my account is locked because it doesn't have a password, i.e.

```
$ passwd -u foo
passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock the password of this account.
```

Petesh solution is correct:

```
usermod -p '*' foo
```

From the man page for shadow:

"If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's telling you the account is *locked*, not that it doesn't have a password. You lock and account to prevent people from logging in using that account; even via SSH. You generally can only switch to a locked account using `su` or `sudo`.

The rules are described in the [`shadow`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) manual page which says:

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

The logic is `*` will never match a password, but doesn't mean locked, while `!` means locked.

This encrypted password is stored, generally, in the shadow file and can be changed using the passwd command or the `usermod` command. If you wish to change the password to one that doesn't work, then you can change to one starting with `*`, which will never match a password, so, for example, using the `usermod` command:

```
bubble ~ [2]> sudo usermod -L freerad
bubble ~> sudo grep freerad /etc/shadow
freerad:!*:16197:0:99999:7:::
```

This is a locked freerad account. ssh should prevent you from logging in using that account even if you use public/private key pairs.

```
bubble ~> sudo usermod -p '*' freerad
bubble ~> sudo grep freerad /etc/shadow
freerad:*:16291:0:99999:7:::
```

This freerad account has a never-matchable password. The account is not locked, but if you were to login using ssh public/private keys it would not prevent you from logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try unlocking it with

```
passwd -u foo
```

Being locked and not having a password are two different things.

Comment: passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock the password of this account.